# How to access an Oracle linked table in Linq2db?

Tags: c#, oracle, linked-tables, linq2db

I have a linked table I access like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM MySchema.Sectors@STATS
```

How do I define that in Linq2db?

I tried:

```
[Table(Schema = "MySchema", Name = "SECTORS@STATS")]
public partial class Sector
```

but when I try to load it, I get

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `Server` property:

```cs
[Table(Schema = "MySchema", Name = "SECTORS", Server = "STATS")]
public partial class Sector
{
   ...
}
```

Also you can do that dynamically when building query:

```cs
var result = db.GetTable<Sector>().ServerName("STATS")
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!